# SSL Certificate Context - How to get it using NPAPI

Tags: ssl, wininet, npapi

How to get the SSL certificate context of the website using NPAPI ? Can I use libnss (Network Security Services) or should I stick to WinINet's InternetQueryOption() to get the context.

Thanks,
Saleh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NPAPI doesn't have anything that could give you that information and, as far as i know, neither has JavaScript in the page.

So there is probably no way around retrieving the URL and using external libraries to get more information about it.