# Get fingerprint of current page's SSL certificate in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, ssl, google-chrome-extension, ssl-certificate, fingerprinting

I'm attempting to write an extension which verifies the SHA1 fingerprint of a site's SSL certificate with a third party. However it doesn't seem to be possible to do this either through native JavaScript or Chrome's extension APIs.

I found this question which would seem to do what I want: [How can I get the SSL Certificate info for the *current* page in a Firefox Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983401/how-can-i-get-the-ssl-certificate-info-for-the-current-page-in-a-firefox-exten)

But unfortunately it is only applicable to Firefox. Is there any way to do this in a cross browser compatible way, or even just in Chrome?

Answer (score 10):

Not as of January 2014 (but there are bug reports on file).

### Firefox

Firefox currently only has a way to provide certificate information passively, without any extension API to be able to block a connection that is deemed to have an inappropriate certificate.  There's [**Mozilla Bug #644640** — "Implement extension point for extensions to influence trust decisions in PSM"](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=644640), which is tracking the ability to decline connections.

### Chromium

Chrome, on the other hand, doesn't even let you examine the certificate in the first place; there's [**Chromium Issue #107793** — "Provide information about the TLS connections to extensions via the webRequest API"](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107793), which appears to track both the ability to simply examine the certificates in the first place, and also to revoke trust, if needed.

(There's also an earlier [Chromium Issue #49469 — "Feature request: Implement Extensions API for accessing information about HTTPS/SSL certificate for web page"](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=49469), but it would seem like Issue #107793 has taken over.)

The draft of Chromium API proposal as linked to Issue 107793 above (note that it's only a draft of the proposed interface, without an actual implementation so far):

- **https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/webrequest-ssl-hooks**

Comment: This sounds like a feature that should be brought up on a standards related mailing list. I follow webapps and webapps-security, but I think there's another for Javascript. You might try the one of the webapps list or one dedicated to Javascript.

Comment: There's a new request open for a read-only API which is in code review: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=628819