# Google Chrome Extension: access padlock/certificate info

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, google-chrome-extension, pki

Okay, a bit of an odd question here, but I'm doing a research project about what influences people to make trust decisions when they look at a website, and without going into all the back story here, I am developing a browser plugin for Google Chrome that identifies the elements that people look for the most in a web page and tries to give a trust rating for that page. One major bit of information is the security certificate and that nice green padlock you see in the omnibox.

I am new to Chrome extension programming and I've searched the Javascript Chrome APIs here: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index, but the omnibox seemed to only allow you to enter search terms. If it isn't possible, are there any alternative ways to see if Chrome trusts the certificate of the current page?

**Question**: Is there any API for getting info about the state of the padlock icon in the omnibox so that my application can know the state of that padlock icon?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get fingerprint of current page's SSL certificate in a Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689724/get-fingerprint-of-current-pages-ssl-certificate-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: A comment: unfortunately, it seems like it's not implemented in Chrome yet, though the feature request status is "available"

Comment: "I'm doing a research project about what influences people to make trust decisions when they look at a website..." - You *need* to thumb through Peter Gutmann's [Engineering Security](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/book.pdf). He goes into it in painful detail with citations to the Security UI studies. Also, you might want to visit [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com/) for your studies.