# Is it possible to query the state of the https "Secure" site info from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to query the state of the https "Secure" site info from a chrome extension?
I have read elsewhere that checking SSL certificates should be left to the browser, and it's not appropriate for JS to be involved. I'm not expecting to influence the browser's decision to accept/reject the certificate, just to view the outcome.

Also, I know that javascript has the `window.isSecureContext` and I could test if `window.location.protocol == 'https:'`
But, these are true if the SSL certificate is invalid, but the user still decides to proceed to the website anyway.

How can I test the state of the "{padlock} Secure" site-information indicator in the OmniBox, from an extension?
Or is possible to test whether the user has chosen to ignore the invalid certificate in some other way?

Comment: AFAIK,this is under development. You can also check this related [SO port](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41569209/5995040), it discussed that it is currently not available, but there's the Chromium API proposal webRequest SSL Hooks.